# For Amazon SES: Using an API to receive the list of bounced emails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Hello is there an Amazon SES API (or some kind of webhook) which allows us to see the list of bounced emails?

I know SNS exists but that costs extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Amazon SES notifications sent by email - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications-email.html):

> Amazon SES can send you email when you receive bounces and complaints by using a process called email feedback forwarding.
>
> In order to send email using Amazon SES, you must configure it to send bounce and complaint notifications by using one of the following methods:
>
> - By **enabling email feedback forwarding**
> - By sending notifications to an Amazon SNS topic
> - By publishing event notifications

So, if you don't want to use an Amazon SNS topic (which is very low cost!), you could have them sent via email.